# I have 2 rows , 1 for timestamp and 1 for status '200 ok', and 'not found', how to get in which day there was more than 1% errors

Tags: python, sql

2 column for timestamp and one for status, I need to get recorded group the timestamp together for each day and then display a number of errors in each day separately, the table name is a log. , I don't need it to give me 1 date and 1 error, I need it collect each day alone and tell me how many errors in it where stack != '200 OK'

select  time, max(time) as errors   (add time separately not  group the days togther' 
from the log where status != '200 OK' group by time order by errors desc; and

```
select distinct time, count(status) as errors
from log having status != '200 OK' group by time order by errors desc;


 example: i need it  output like this:
 2010-1-5 19:52:11 errors = 50

not like this 
2010-1-5 19:52:11 errors = 1
2010-1-5 19:52:12 errors = 1
2010-1-5 19:52:13 errors = 1
2010-1-6 19:52:11 errors = 1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, you need to extract the date from the time column.  Often, this is done by converting to `date`:

```
select cast(time as date) as dte, count(*) as errors
from log
where status <> '200 OK'
group by cast(time as date)
order by errors desc;
```

EDIT:

If you want the ratio as well, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select cast(time as date) as dte,
       sum(case when status <> '200 OK' then 1 else 0 end) as errors,
       avg(case when status <> '200 OK' then 1.0 else 0 end) as error_rate           
from log
where 
group by cast(time as date)
order by error_rate desc;
```

Comment: ok that's give me sperate time and number of errors for each day how I get in which days there was more than 1 % errors

Comment: can you answer please how I get in which day more than 1% errors

Answer (score 0):

Give `min(time)`.

For it to count everyday then you have to extract date from time field and group by that date.

Eg,

```
select to_date(time,'dd-mm-yyyy'), count(status) as errors
from log having status != '200 OK' group by to_date(time,'dd-mm-yyyy') order by errors desc;
```

And to get a percentage of errors, use `case` statement.